# Split string by comma not inside quotes or brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I'm quite familiar with regex, yet found the following hard to solve.

I am trying to split a (CSS selector) string (using regex) by a comma that is not nested in `""`, `''`, `[]` or `()`.

I successfully managed to do that, but only with one of the symbols [`""` or `''` or `()`], but not with all of them together. I used the following regex for quotes for example:

```regex
(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

Example of input with a mark under the commas that should separate the parts:

```css
#id.class:contains("text with ,") , #id2[attr="value,"]:contains(,) , [attr='value,']
                                  ^                                 ^
```

This should split to:

- `#id.class:contains("text with ,")`
- `#id2[attr="value,"]:contains(,)`
- `[attr='value,']`

Is that possible to do?

Comment: My initial approach would be `[...input.matchAll(/(\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]|[^,])+/g)].map(m => m[0])`  Not sure about quotes though.  Quotes can be escaped in CSS selectors so that further complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

If the brackets are not nested, then you could use the following:

```js
let s = `#id.class:contains("text with ,") , #id2[attr="value,"]:contains(,) , [attr='value,']`;

let regex = /(?:(["'])(\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|\[(?:(["'])(\\.|(?!\2)[^\\])*\2|[^\]])*\]|\((?:(["'])(\\.|(?!\3)[^\\])*\3|[^)])*\)|[^,])+/g;

let parts = s.match(regex);
for (let part of parts) console.log(part);
```

## Breaking it down

The expression breaks into four parts, split by `|` (OR):

1. `(["'])(\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1`
2. `\[(?:(["'])(\\.|(?!\2)[^\\])*\2|[^\]])*\]`
3. `\((?:(["'])(\\.|(?!\3)[^\\])*\3|[^)])*\)`
4. `[^,]`

The first three have `(["'])(\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1` (but with `\2` and `\3` respectively): these all capture a quoted part, either with double or single quotes. The first one is for stand-alone quotes, the second one is for quotes within square brackets, and the third is for quotes within parentheses. The `\\.` takes care of backslashes which escape the next character.

The fourth alternative, is the catch-all: for any non-special character that does not occur in quotes or parentheses. This should not be a comma, as that is the separator.

These four options are repeatable, hence the wrapping `(?: ...... )+`